# How to import .rep on another .rep ? Qt Remote Object

Tags: c++, qt, qtremoteobjects

It’s been a few days, I'm facing a problem. I want to write two rep files with one POD on each file.

So, I have a file a.rep :

```
POD A(int id , QString label)
```

And a b.rep :

```
POD B(int id, QList<A> aList)
```

To include the type A on the file b.rep, I tried :

- #include "a.rep"
- #include <a.rep>
- #include A
- #include "rep_a_replica.h" (Work but just on client side)

Finally, I wrote these lines of code on my header b.rep:

```
#if defined(REP_B_REPLICA_H)
#include "rep_a_replica.h"
#endif
#if defined(REP_B_SOURCE_H)
#include "rep_a_source.h"
#endif
```

With this lines, the type A is recognized. But when I send by my server a type B, the client cannot read the type A and print on the console :

```
QSQ_: unable to load type 'A', returning an empty list
```

So, my question is :

Have you a better method to import the type A ? If not, have you an idea of why I can't read the type A on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a qMetaTypeId() solve the problem.